# Saving sessions to pass to other pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a user management system where the types of users are "admins" and "users". If the logged in user is admin he gets access to few pages. If the role is user he gets access to only one page. I need to save the session of the admin/user and check every time if he is "admin" so that the user doesn't illegally access information by just passing the URL. For now I can just save the name of the user but not his role. What do I do to pass the ROLE to next set of pages.

Home.php

```
   session_start();
   if( $_SESSION["logging"] && $_SESSION["logged"] )
  {
  echo $_SESSION[user];
  //Can be accessed only by admin 
  dashboard();
  }
  if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
   { 
  $number_of_rows=checkpass();
     if($number_of_rows==1)
        {   
         $_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];
         $_SESSION[logged]=true;
         print"<h1>you have loged in successfully</h1>";
         if($res['ROLE']=='user')
         {
                      //Accessible only by user.
         print "<h3><a href='user.php'>View Users</a></h3>";
                 logout();
         }
        }
        else
        {
            print "Please enter your log in information!";  
            loginform();
        }
    } 
    function checkpass()
    {
     //Database query
     if($res['ROLE']=='admin')
     { 
       //Redirected 
       dashboard();
     }
```

Comment: You can save the role also in a session, something like this:
`$_SESSION['user']['role'] = $role;`

And you can check it like this: `if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] != 'admin') exit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this were ever required

```
$_SESSION['role']= role of the user;
```

Get $_SESSION['role'] in other pages.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
if($res['ROLE']=='user')
{
     $_SESSION['ROLE'] = "user";
                  //Accessible only by user.
     print "<h3><a href='user.php'>View Users</a></h3>";
     logout();
}

if($res['ROLE']=='admin')
 { 
   $_SESSION['ROLE'] = "admin";
   //Redirected 
   dashboard();
 }
```

for getting the `ROLE` use in other pages

```
echo $_SESSION['ROLE'];
```

Comment: @Sindu in next.php write at top `session_start();` and after that `echo $_SESSION['ROLE'];`. It will work.